# CSV file is not found by d3 libary in nodeJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I want to test out the library [TechanJS](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/af8674d57980790137a0).

My plan is to put in some real time data and plot it to the screen.

However, I created a index.ejs in my nodeJS project and just wanted to try the [sample out](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/af8674d57980790137a0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    path.line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 1;
    }

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://techanjs.org/techan.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

    var x = techan.scale.financetime()
            .range([0, width])
            .outerPadding(0);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var close = techan.plot.close()
            .xScale(x)
            .yScale(y);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        var accessor = close.accessor();

        data = data.slice(0, 200).map(function(d) {
            return {
                date: parseDate(d.Date),
                open: +d.Open,
                high: +d.High,
                low: +d.Low,
                close: +d.Close,
                volume: +d.Volume
            };
        }).sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(accessor.d(a), accessor.d(b)); });

        x.domain(data.map(accessor.d));
        y.domain(techan.scale.plot.ohlc(data, accessor).domain());

        svg.append("g")
                .datum(data)
                .attr("class", "close")
                .call(close);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Price ($)");
    });

    console.log("test", d3);

</script>
```

When looking at the console I get:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/data.csv"
data.csv
TypeError: data is undefined

data = data.slice(0, 200).map(function(d) {
localhost:3000 (Row 62, Column 8)
```

I put my data.csv in the same folder as my `index.ejs`.

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put data.csv on your assets folder if you use something like the static middleware, eg. on public/data and reference it as "data/data.csv" on your code like this (not tested but I believe something similar should work)

```
d3.csv("data/data.csv", function(error, data) {...}
```

or, you can create a new route serving the file upon request, say (if you use express)

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('path/to/data.csv', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```